# ByteBuffer out of bounds exception

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception, bytebuffer

I have a ByteBuffer in which an RGBA image of arbitrary dimensions is stored. I'm trying to overlay certain parts of that image with triangles of a single, random, RGBA colour. However, I'm getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException, which doesn't make sense to me.

```
public ByteBuffer getByteBuffer()
{
    /*Creates a ByteBuffer containing an image of a single background colour. A single pixel in the image is
    represented as a float array of size 4*/
    ByteBuffer buffer = Helpers.getBGByteBuffer(new float[]{1f, 1f, 1f, 1f}, width * height * 4 * Float.BYTES);
    ByteBuffer triBuffer;
    int        offset;

    for(RenderTriangle triangle : triangleList)
    {
        offset = triangle.getOffset().y; //Indicates the offset (position) of the triangle in relation to the image
        triBuffer = triangle.getByteBuffer(); //Gets the ByteBuffer of the triangle.

        for(int i = 0; i < triBuffer.capacity(); i += 4 * Float.BYTES) //Float.BYTES = 4
        {
            byte[] rgba1 = new byte[4 * Float.BYTES];
            byte[] rgba2 = new byte[4 * Float.BYTES];

            triBuffer.get(rgba1, i, rgba1.length); //Throws exception for i = 16
            buffer.get(rgba2, offset + i, rgba2.length);

            byte[] rgbaAdded = Helpers.addBytesAsFloats(rgba1, rgba2); //Calculates resulting RGBA value

            buffer = buffer.put(rgbaAdded, offset + i, rgbaAdded.length);
        }
    }
    return buffer;
}
```

The above code throws the Exception on the second iteration of the for-loop (so i = 16) at

```
triBuffer.get(rgba1, i, rgba1.length),
```

Some relevant debug values at the second iteration, just before the exception is thrown:

```
offset = 0 
i = 16
rgba1 = {byte[16]@xxx}
rgba2 = {byte[16]@xxx}
triBuffer = {HeapByteBuffer@xxx}"java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=16 lim=64 cap=64]"
buffer = {HeapByteBuffer@xxx}"java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=32 lim=64 cap=64]"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the line is incorrect.

As ByteBuffer is a buffer, it uses its own index to keep track of where it was, so when you read 16 bytes, the next time you read, you will read the next 16 bytes (you don't go back to the beginning).

In your line, the `i` parameter actually stands for the position of the destination array to insert to.

So I think the correct line should be: `triBuffer.get(rgba1, 0, rgba1.length)`

Maybe you need to do the same for the other ByteBuffer, I'm not sure.

Comment: That was indeed the problem, I also had to rewind `buffer` 16 bytes after each get operation to account for the buffer position moving after reading from it.